# Sample size calculation from two ROC curves with a different ratio of cases to controls than sample data

Tags: r, roc

I'm trying to compare two AUC values, for sample size calculation in the `pROC` package. The package takes inputs roc1 and roc2 and determines the number of cases and controls from those curves. I would like to use those curves as input, and calculate the sample size needed to achieve a certain level of power; however, I want to use a different ratio of cases to controls than the data I provide. The kappa argument in pROC::power.roc.test does not appear to work unless I'm misunderstanding how to use this function.

```
library(pROC)

# Using iris dataset in R
# Just changing the `virginica` to `setosa` to have only two levels. 
iris[which(iris$Species == 'virginica'),]$Species <- "setosa"
iris$Species <- factor(iris$Species, levels  = c("setosa", "versicolor"))

roc1 <- roc(Species ~ Sepal.Length, data = iris)
roc2 <- roc(Species ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)

power.roc.test(roc1, roc2, power =0.9)

power.roc.test(roc1, roc2, power = 0.9, kappa = 1.7)

power.roc.test(roc1, roc2, power = 0.9, kappa = banana)
```

All the `power.roc.test` calls produce the same numbers of cases and controls.

[image: power.roc.test output]

Am I using the package wrong? Am I understanding the stats behind ROC curve sample size estimation incorrectly?

I looked in the source code, and it seemed like kappa was just recalculated based on the given cases and controls. I tried carrying the kappa through the function but I confess that I'm not the most adept at class methods.

Comment: This is fully consistent with the documentation. Are you really interested in confirming this, or are you implicitly after a workaround to define use a custom kappa?